# Prefix_to_Postfix: multiplication not appearing in correct place

Tags: python, expression, postfix-mta, prefix

I'm new to python programming, and i am writing a function that takes a string containing a prefix notation mathematical expression, builds a binary tree, and then traverses it to produce an equivalent postfix notation expression.

when i tested the code using the below assert, the first 2 asset ("5") == "5") and ("+ 10 20") == "10 20 +"), seems to work as expected. But for the final assert:

- Input: * + 1 2 - 5 3
- Output: * 1 2 + 5 3-
- Expected: 1 2 + 5 3 - *

**Please advice why the * is appearing at the start and not at the end. many thanks.**

```
assert(prefix_to_postfix("5") == "5")
assert(prefix_to_postfix("+ 10 20") == "10 20 +")
assert(prefix_to_postfix("* + 1 2 - 5 3") == "1 2 + 5 3 - *")
```

CODE

```
OPERATORS = set(['+', '-', '*', '/', '(', ')', '^'])
PRIORITY = {'+': 1, '-': 1, '*': 2, '/': 2, '^': 3}

def prefix_to_postfix(expression):
    stack = []
    output = ''
    for ch in expression:
        if ch not in OPERATORS:
            output += ch
        elif ch == '(':
            stack.append('(')
        elif ch == ')':
            while stack and stack[-1] != '(':
                output += stack.pop()
            stack.pop()
        else:
            while stack and stack[-1] != '(' and PRIORITY[ch] <= PRIORITY[stack[-1]]:
                output += stack.pop()
            stack.append(ch)
    while stack:
        output += stack.pop()
    return output

expression = input('Enter expression: ')
print(prefix_to_postfix(expression))
```

Comment: for PRIORITY (PRIORITY = {'+': 1, '-': 1, '*': 2, '/': 2, '^': 3}) set the correct priority e.g follow the BODMAS